# MediaException: UNKNOWN : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player

Tags: java, ubuntu, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have trying JavaFx MediaPlayer on ubuntu, but when run it tells me

```
"MediaException: UNKNOWN : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!"
```

Anyone know how to solve it?
I have tried most of what I can google-ed, have installed ffmpeg, java8, and jfxrt.jar.
Is there an easier way or module testing method on this?
Thanks in advance!

Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
java -version = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_77-b03)

```
    System.out.println("Hello World");
    File f = new File("a.mp3");
    System.out.println("F=" + f.exists());

    try {
        final Media media = new Media(f.toURI().toString());
        final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
        mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);
        mediaPlayer.play();
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Toolkit not initialised
[java]  at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(PlatformImpl.java:273)
[java]  at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(PlatformImpl.java:268)
[java]  at javafx.application.Platform.runLater(Platform.java:[java]    at javafx.scene.media.Media$_MetadataListener.onMetadata(Media.java:[java]  at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.MetadataParserImpl.done(MetadataParserImpl.java:120)
[java]  at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.platform.java.ID3MetadataParser.parse(ID3MetadataParser.java:237)
[java]  at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.MetadataParserImpl.run(MetadataParserImpl.java:103)
[java] MediaException: UNKNOWN : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player! : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!
[java]  at javafx.scene.media.MediaException.exceptionToMediaException(MediaException.java:146)
[java]  at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.init(MediaPlayer.java:511)
[java]  at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.<init>(MediaPlayer.java:414)
[java]  at jarvis.main(jarvis.java:24)
[java] Caused by: com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!
[java]  at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.getPlayer(NativeMediaManager.java:274)
[java]  at com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaManager.getPlayer(MediaManager.java:118)
[java]  at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.init(MediaPlayer.java:467)
[java]  ... 2 more
```